# Error: Controller 'carousel', required by directive 'slide', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, carousel, ui.bootstrap

**Summary :**

Whenever I try to use the `data-slide` in the `HTML DOM`, I get this error in my js console:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'carousel', required by directive
> 'slide', can't be found!

I created a application with bootstrap and angularjs. I already added this library `<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`.

I've included **`ui.bootstrap`** as a dependency when creating my app.

**Entire error:**

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'carousel', required by directive 'slide', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.10/$compile/ctreq?p0=carousel&p1=slide
    at angular.js:68
    at getControllers (angular.js:8432)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8570)
    at angular.js:8810
    at processQueue (angular.js:15097)
    at angular.js:15113
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16359)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16175)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16467)
    at done (angular.js:10852)
```

**Relevant part of the template:**

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
</div>
```

When I removed `data-slide="prev"` & `data-slide="next"` this error not coming.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve the conflict by adding the `ng-non-bindable` to the elements that have the `data-slide` directive :

```
  <a data-slide="prev" href="#clients-slider" ng-non-bindable class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
```